# How can I encrypt a file in ASP.Net and decrypt it in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, encryption, cryptography

I have an application that encrypts a collection of files, zips them up and exposes them over the internet. A Silverlight application then downloads the zip file, and attemps to decrypt each file.

The problem I have is that the encryption code I have written for the .Net app cannot be used for the Silverlight app since the CLR is different - a fairly major oversight on my part.

The original c#.Net code for creating the algorithm is:

```
private static SymmetricAlgorithm CreateRijndael(string password, byte[] salt)
{
    var derivedBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 1000);

    SymmetricAlgorithm sma = Rijndael.Create();
    sma.KeySize = 256;
    sma.Key = derivedBytes.GetBytes(32);
    sma.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    return sma;
}
```

However, Rijndael isn't exposed in Silverlight. How can I modify this so that I can compile it for Silverlight whilst using the same code for my .Net app?

Comment: As silverlight runs on the client, am I wrong to think any skilled developper can decompile the xap file and retrieve password/salt values ?

Comment: @Steve B, Possibly, but in this case the password value is not part of the compiled application.

Comment: @Steven, because the concern isn't whether the transfer of information is secure but once the files have been downloaded whether they can be accessed easily.

Comment: If you want to send files encrypted over the internet, authenticate the users on the server and use a secure (HTTPS / SSL) connection. The browser/server infrastructure will in that case ensure that everything is safe, without you having to do a thing. What you're trying to do seems very odd to me.

Comment: If you download over SSL, files can always be accessed easily.

Comment: @Steven, I think you misunderstand and you are also making assumptions without knowing the full details of the project. We are actually using SSL. However, the client wants encrypted files. Encrypted even when downloaded so that they can not be opened easily without doing so via a specific SL app. Either way, I appreciate your comments but they do not address the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `Rijndael` is not exposed in Silverlight the `Aes` implementation is.

**AES** is Rijndael with a block size of 128 bits, IOW it disallow using the 192 and 256 bits **block** size. Since `Rijndael` in .NET defaults to 128 bits **block** size then you should be able to interoperate without any issue (unless you used another **block** size).

If you really get stuck on some other cryptographic feature missing in Silverlight then I suggest you to copy/paste what you require from the Mono class libraries.